# Changing html of selected text on click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, highlight, getselection

i'm trying to add some text on selected text after click on button.

I have a contenteditable area like in that picture below.

And i want to select text and after that selection when i click the B icon i wanna add some html tags around the selected text like

```
<b>make this text bold</b>
```

or etc.

[image]

I found these codes on stackoverflow;

This one returns me the selection as text.

```
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}
```

This one changes the html of text as desired if i use them together.

```
function replaceSelectionWithHtml(html) {
    var range;
    if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().getRangeAt) {
        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = html;
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), child;
        while ( (child = div.firstChild) ) {
            frag.appendChild(child);
        }
        range.insertNode(frag);
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.pasteHTML(html);
    }
}
replaceSelectionWithHtml("<b>" + getSelectionText() + "</b>");
```

But when i click on the icon it loose focus and choose button as selection and replaceSelectionWithHtml() runs for the B icon.

How am i gonna active these task?

Here is the codepen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybzzXZ
It's not fully functional but i will give you a better idea.

Comment: Could you create a working snippet of the problem you are facing? Or add the relevant html code

Comment: Please follow @Carsten Løvbo Andersen advice and do the same for all your questions. It is important to always have a snippet. codepen is good.

Comment: Actually its a little bit complex system but i will try to make working snippet.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico It's not always important to have a snippet, but it's a good idea to have one when the problem is hard to `debug` without

Comment: @WosleyAlarico no need to use codepen SO has `<>`

Comment: I couldnt make it fully work but i think this will give a better idea.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybzzXZ

Answer (score 1):

```
    function getSelectionText() {
        var text = "";
        if (window.getSelection) {
        alert(window.getSelection())
            text = window.getSelection();
        } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
            text = document.selection.createRange().text;
        }
        return text;
    }



    var selection;
  var isDown = false;

$(".nText").mousedown(function(){
    isDown = true;
});

$(document).mouseup(function(){
    if(isDown){
      selection = getSelectionText();
        alert(selection);

        //do something
        isDown = false;
    }
}); 
    document.onmouseup = document.onkeyup = document.onselectionchange = function() {



    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this solves the problem. You can just take the text and replace it. This does not work as intended when you have a single word which is multiple times in the p element. However, look at the selection part. There you see why your code didn't work.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QvqqXP

```html
<h3>How to make bold selection text after click the button</h3>
<p>I wanna add < b>< /b> tags around selected text after click that span#bold-text</p>
<p id="empty-line" class="nText selectedT" contenteditable="true">make bold some part of this text.</p>
<span id="bold-text">Click</span>
```

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#empty-line{
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
}

span{
  cursor: poniter;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

p:focus {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    function getSelectionText() {
        var text = "";
        if (window.getSelection) {
            text = window.getSelection().toString();
        } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
            text = document.selection.createRange().text;
        }
        return text;
    }

    var selection;
    document.onmouseup = document.onkeyup = document.onselectionchange = function() {
        if ($('.nText').is(":focus")) {
            selection = getSelectionText();
        }
    };

    function replaceSelectionWithHtml(html) {
        var pos = $('.nText')[0].innerHTML.replace(selection, html);
        $('.nText')[0].innerHTML = pos;
    }

    $('span#bold-text').click(function(e) {
        replaceSelectionWithHtml("<b>" + selection + "</b>");
    });

});
```

Comment: Hey this is really what i'm looking for but if that text has includes same word 2 or more times it affects first match even if i not choose that.

Comment: @SedatYusufErgüneş yes i already said that. i never worked with selection but it has functions where you can get the direct position.

Comment: ahah sorry i forgot the beginning of the message after working code :)

Answer (score 0):

You should exclude the buttons selection on your function.

```
if(text!='bold_selection_result')
```